# For finding limit of $ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} +1}$ , why L'Hospital rule is not working?

Tags: limits

So for evaluating limit of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} +1 } $
I used De l'Hospital rule, as conditions are being satisfied,

a) $f(x),g(x)\to \infty $

b) both are differential

And upon using L'Hospital rule I get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{1/x} (-1/x^2)}{e^{1/x} (-1/x^2)} $ , cancelling denominator with numerator i get 1.

But evaluating left hand and right hand limit separately shows that this function does not have limiting value at $x\to 0$

I don't understand what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: $e^{1/x}\not \to \infty$ when $x \to 0$

Comment: They don’t go to infinity at 0 - the right limit is +infinity and the left is -infinity, so you need to be careful. Despite that, I do agree with 1 happening to be correct. If you divide the top and bottom by e^(1/x), you get the ratio of two expressions which have limit 1.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2232656/505767